# Can I use parameters in django template tag

Tags: django

I want to send base template I am extending as a parameter.

Currently, my template first tag is like this

```
{% extends "rent_base.html" %}
```

I want it to be like this

```
{% extends {{base}} %}
```

Can I achieve it with Django templates?

Comment: `{% extends base %}`?..

Comment: You can't use `{{}}` inside `{% %}`. But inside `{% %}` you can just use python epxressions.